# Using dynamic scope variable name in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Have anyone use something like this. I cant parse {{}} uin ng-repeat its working fine with ng-options

```
<option value="" ng-repeat="k in selected_grp_keys_{{value.key.id}}" value="{{k.id}}" ng-selected="k.id == value.fk_key">{{ k.display_name }}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a function that returns the values

HTML:

```
<option value="" ng-repeat="k in getValues(value.key.id)" value="{{k.id}}" ng-selected="k.id == value.fk_key">{{ k.display_name }}</option>
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.getValues = function (id) {
  return $scope['selected_grp_keys_' + id];
}
```

Edit: As an aside, ngRepeats are not ideal for select-options. AngularJS has an ngOptions directive for the select element that does the same thing. Read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions